# How to show a custom row and still use UIDatePicker in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to user to input expiration duration.

For that i want to have everything like uidatepicker would show, but have a top row, saying never expire.

Is it possible, other than re-writing the whole uidatepicker using uipicker ?

Thanks in advance for any pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

Purely at a UIDatePicker perspective, this is not possible. Why not just use a toggle button like Expires : YES/ NO and based on the user selection - toggle the visibility of UIDatePicker. Like Apple, I would not suggest you to rewrite the UIDatepicker completely. This always confuses the user.

Comment: that would mean that user has to go through extra steps

Comment: Yes, you are right and i hate it so much. It is not ideal! So, how are your values? Do you have numeric values

Comment: yes i want user to select a date when something will expire, and one of the option is to never expire........ i could create a custom ui picker and ask user to select days, hours and minutes and have one of the options as never expire, but thats not ideal

Comment: If you use a [custom Picker from cocoa control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/afpickerview). Can you get away with initial state of 0 for all the days,hours and minutes? 0 essentially means never expires?